# How to report and interpret a parameter of a SEM model with categorical and continuous variables

Tags: categorical-data, structural-equation-modeling, continuous-data

I have conducted a SEM model in MPlus where X and Y are categorical and M is continuous. So the path from X to Y are log odds, the path from X to M are betas, and the path from M to Y are log odds. I used the "model constraint" command to calculate the indirect effect of X to Y through M which has given me some significant results but I wondered what parameter is used to report this indirect effect? Also, how would you interpret this indirect effect?

For example, one model looks at associations of SES (four levels) and alcohol use (four levels) with social support as a continuous mediator. The output of MPlus tells me that the path from SES to alcohol use is OR=4.20 (95% CI=2.49-7.11), the path from SES to social support is B=-0.30 (SE=0.03, p<0.01), the path from social support to alcohol use is OR=0.91 (95% CI=0.86-0.96). The indirect effect of social support is B=0.20 (SE=0.06, p<0.01). So I know that the indirect effect is significant but what parameter is used/reported if there is an odds ratio and beta to calculate this, and how can this finding be interpreted?

Comment: I believe this case is covered in this article: https://doi.org/10.1037/a0020761